# ViewModel VS Static / Object

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel

Пытаюсь найти фундаментальную разницу между `ViewModel` и `Static(java)` или `Object(kotlin)`.
Основной аргумент, который я вижу в статьях, это то, что ViewModel переживает поворот Activity.
Но ведь тоже самое делают и статичные методы и объекты?
И LiveData ведет в статичных местах себя как и во ViewModel.
Зачем придумывать что-то новое, когда в языке уже есть велосипед?

К тому же ViewModel отлично работает только во фрагментах при общей Активити. Если надо обратиться к одной модели из разных Активити - надо немного потанцевать с бубном, чтобы верно указать владельца. У статиков такой проблемы нет.

**ViewModel**

```
class MyVM : ViewModel() {
  var a: String = "Hello!"
}


//////////////////////
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var vm: MyVM


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        vm = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyVM::class.java)

        textView.settext(vm.a.value)
}
```

**Object / Static**

```
object VM{
    var a: String = "Hello!"
}


//////////////////////
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {  

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)        

        textView.settext(VM.a)
}
```

Comment: Ну, например ViewModel  интегрируется в жизненный цикл - самоудаляется при смерти связанной активити, имеет безопасный контекст. Для своего статик- класса нужно все самому писать

Comment: @pavlofff можете пнуть в какую сторону гуглить? что за методы? какая интеграция в жизненный цикл?

Comment: Исправил комент, сперва не о том подумал. Насчет контекста - класс AndroidViewModel с собственным контекстом, защищающим от утечек

Answer (score 2):

ViewModel привязывается к активити или фрагменту и переживает их смену конфигурации, но это не означает, что она живёт вечно, как статик или object. При полном уничтожении активити или фрагмента (выход из экрана) ViewModel уничтожается вместе с ними, освобождая занятые ресурсы. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "полным уничтожением"? для Активити, я там понимают finish() / onDestroy. а для Фрагмента?

Comment: @Wlad "полным уничтожением" я подразумеваю ситуацию, когда Активити/Фрагмент уничтожается и не пересоздаётся, например при нажатии кнопки назад. При смене конфигурации Активити/Фрагмент тоже уничтожаются, но при этом сразу пересоздаются.

Comment: владельцем ViewModel должен быть наследник AppCompatActivity. соответственно VM очиститься, только при onDestroy активити-владельца. если приложение состоит из 1 активити и кучи фрагментов, никакого профита в производительности, по сравнению со Static нет (VM будет жить, пока живо приложение). если есть несколько Активити - VM надо немного подшаманить через Factory и статичные методы и тогда она будет жить, пока живет все приложение, а не только Активити. где выгода? p.s. я в упор не вижу РЕАЛЬНЫХ преимуществ. если есть какой-то жизненный пример - буду только рад.

Comment: я не понимаю, пока что, о чем вы говорите =( в моем представлении, ViewModel нужна для сохранения данных при повороте экране и как "общий ресурс" для общения между Активити / Фрагментами.

Comment: @Wlad владельцем может быть и фрагмент, не обязательно все вьюмодели на активити вешать. К тому же вью модель позволяет получить объект [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate), который позволяет сохранять состояние вьюмедели и восстанавливать это состояние, если приложение было убито системой и запущено снова. И зачем вообще вообще шарить вью модель нескольким активити? Используйте лучше две вью модели и один репозиторий. И вообще, как будете тестировать ваш статик, а зависимости как внедрять будете?